# rule based labeling of point layer using intersections method on another polygon layer

Tags: qgis, labeling, intersection, expression, filter

I try to make a rule based labeling for my locations point layer which should be displayed, if a point intersects with the value *residential* in a (osm) layer called *landuse*. So I tried to do:

```
intersect($geometry,geometry(get_feature(('landuse','fclass','residential')))
```

I'm already using the `intersect()` method elsewhere but in this case without success.

I'm aware of using a workaround but I still need the expression for another case so I would be very glad if someone could help me out here.

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: all names are visible] | [image: only points intersecting with "residential" are labeled] |

Qgis 3.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your current expression checks, whether your current geometry intersects with the geometry of the first entry of the landuse layer where `fclass` is `residential`.

Use the following instead:

`overlay_intersects('landuse',filter:= fclass='residential')`

It checks, whether your current geometry intersects with the layer `landuse`, with the additional filter for features with the value `residential` in the `fclass`-field.

[image]

Comment: awesome, thank you so much for the response AND the explanation. It helped a lot!